# Should Events be externally mutable?

Tags: scala, haskell, programming-languages, functional-programming, frp

I am playing around with FRP and was wondering about how the act of an Event 'occurring' should be handled publicly. By this, I mean should a programmer be able to do the following within an FRP context:

```
event.occur(now, 5)
```

I have never seen examples of this in any FRP papers and it doesn't feel right to me. I feel that FRP frameworks should really hide this type of action and that occurrences of Events should happen behind the scenes only. Am I correct in thinking this?

To clarify, my approach would be to have 'occur' only accessible to the Event class itself. If an abstraction for some external source was needed (such as a mouse) this could be built by extending the Event class. In this way all the logic dealing with occurrence creation is abstracted.

Comment: I've updated my answer in response to your clarification :)

Comment: Thanks! I realised I hadn't really been clear enough :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, if the FRP library exposes a way to bind to external events — e.g. an existing event-based framework — then it *must* provide functionality equivalent to this, or it couldn't interact with the outside world.

However, the question is really: what do you mean by "external"? The FRP system itself is usually taken to be pure, so the idea of executing side-effectful code like `event.occur(now, 5)` from inside the FRP system isn't even meaningful. Generally, of course, a facility to execute such code in response to FRP events *is* provided, but this is usually taken not as part of the pure programming model, but as a facility to interface the network as a whole with the outside world.

So, in my opinion, there's two possible ways to interpret this question:

1. **Should it be possible to trigger an event from outside of the FRP system?** — definitely yes, as it's required for interfacing with the outside world, but this does not affect the programming model of FRP itself.
2. **Should it be possible to trigger an event from "inside" of the FRP system, assuming some facility for executing side-effectful code in reaction to an event?** — also yes, because allowing normal side-effectful code to cause events but forbidding it inside the code executed in response to events seems like a very strange (and circumventable) restriction, given that the intention of the facility is to interface with the outside world.

Indeed, it's possible to cause something just like #2 even if you explicitly forbid it: consider setting things up so that `switchToWindow 3` is executed when the event `buttonClicked` triggers, e.g. (using [reactive-banana](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Reactive-banana) notation):

```
reactimate (switchToWindow 3 <$ buttonClicked)
```

And say that we have an event

```
newWindowFocused :: Event Int
```

The reaction we've set up causes the `newWindowFocused` event to fire, even if firing events from inside code executed due to an event is prevented.

Now, everything I've said so far concerns only "external" events: those not expressed with pure FRP, but explicitly created to represent events that occur in the outside world, beyond the FRP system. If you're asking whether there should be a facility to cause special occurrences in *purely-defined* events, then my response is: absolutely not! This destroys the meaning of the system, because suddenly `fmap f (union e1 e2)` doesn't mean "occurs with value `f x` when either `e1` or `e2` occurs with value `x`", but instead "occurs with value `f x` when either `e1` or `e2` occurs with value `x`... or when some external code randomly decides to fire it".

Not only would such a facility make reasoning about the behaviour of an FRP system essentially meaningless,<sup>1</sup> it'd also violate referential transparency: if you construct two events equivalent to `fmap f (union e1 e2)`, then you can distinguish them by firing one and noticing that the other doesn't occur. You simply can't prevent this in all cases: imagine `fmap g (union e1 e2)`, where `f` computes the same function as `g`; equality on functions is not decidable :)

Of course, it's entirely possible to implement FRP in an impure language, but I think providing a way to violate the referential transparency of the FRP system itself is a very bad thing, as it is, after all, a pure model.

If I understand it correctly, your solution to this flaw in the API (namely, exposing `occur` publicly, which breaks referential transparency of equivalent events, etc. as I talked about above) would be to make `occur` internal to your `Event` class, so that it cannot be used from outside. I agree that, if you need `occur` internally, this is the correct solution. I also agree that it's reasonable to expose it to subclasses if your implementation of external events is done by subclassing `Event`. That falls under "outside world glue", which falls outside the purvue of the FRP model itself, so it's perfectly OK to give it the ability to "break the rules" in this way — after all, that's essentially what it's *for:* disturbing the system with side-effects :)

So, in conclusion:

**No,** events should not expose this interface.

**Yes,** you are correct in thinking this :)

<sup>1</sup> Of course, you could argue that external events do this *full stop*, as the whole behaviour of the system ultimately depends on the "edges" hooked up to the outside world, but this isn't really true: yes, you can't really assume anything about the external events *themselves*, but you can still rely on everything you build out of them to obey the laws of their constructions. Offering an "external firing" facility to every event means that no construction *has* any laws.